# currentUser not work or not exist in firebase 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

```
const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
```

user return null !!

and this not

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    console.log(user.email);
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing seems like the expected behavior to me.

When you access `auth.currentUser`, it gives you the current user when that code runs. Firebase automatically restores the user's credentials when a page loads and this requires a call to the server. This means that when your `auth.currentUser` runs, that call may not have completed yet, and thus the current user is `null`.

When on the other hand you use `onAuthStateChanged`, Firebase only calls your code when it has completed the first check of the user's credentials. So now your code runs after the user has been signed in, and user is no longer `null`.

This is one of the main reasons it's almost always better to use an auth state listener.

Comment: what is this 'auth stte listener' ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. An auth *state* listener is what you add with `onAuthStateChanged`.

Comment: oh well, am sorry i am from latan a think what  'auth stte listener'  is a function wat me idk

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of these:

```js
this.user$ = authState(auth);
```

OR

```js
this.user$ = new Observable((observer: any) =>
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, observer)
);
```

OR

```js
this.user$ = user(auth);
```

and get the Promise version like so:

```js
const user = await this.user$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
```